# Selecting objects from a table using IN

Tags: mysql, sql

That title is probably terrible so let me try to explain with an example

I have a table that consists of top 10 teams called _top 10.  In order to select all the teams that have played a top 10 team at home I can run this query.

```
SELECT      g.home_team,
            IFNULL(SUM(g.home_wins), 0) AS formula 
FROM        games g
WHERE 
            away_team IN (SELECT team_id FROM _top_10) 
GROUP BY    g.home_team 
ORDER BY    formula DESC
```

This will return a list of all the teams that have played top 10 teams at home along with a number of home many wins against top 10 teams at home they have.  What I want included in this list is all the teams that haven't played a top 10 team at home and obviously a zero for wins against top 10 teams at home.   Hope this makes sense.

Here is the union code I tried in order to combine the results

```
SELECT      g.home_team,
            IFNULL(SUM(g.home_wins), 0) AS formula ,
            t.*
FROM        games g
INNER JOIN _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id

UNION

SELECT      g.home_team,
            SUM(0) AS formula ,
            t.*
FROM        games g
LEFT JOIN _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id
WHERE t.team_id IS NULL
GROUP BY    g.home_team 
ORDER BY    formula DESC;
```

**UPDATE**

I've put everything together and I'm getting

> Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Here is my final query

```
SELECT     IF(@last_ranking <> formula, @current_rankings := @current_rankings + 1, @current_rankings)  AS rank, 
            @last_ranking := formula, 
            prequery.team, 
            prequery.formula
FROM        (select @current_rankings := 0) sqlvars, 
            (SELECT    team, 
                        SUM(score) formula 
            FROM (SELECT     g.home_team, 
                            SUM(CASE WHEN t.team_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g.home_wins END) AS formula 
            FROM            games g LEFT JOIN 
                        _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id 
            WHERE       
                        g.season = 2012 AND 
                        g.completed = 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT     g.away_team, 
                        SUM(CASE WHEN t2.team_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g.away_wins END) AS formula 
            FROM        games g LEFT JOIN 
                        _top_10 AS t2 ON g.home_team = t2.team_id 
            WHERE      
                        g.season = 2012 AND 
                        g.completed = 1), 
                            (SELECT @current_rankings := 0, @last_ranking := 0) r 
                GROUP BY team ORDER BY formula DESC ) prequery;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` the tables instead of the `IN` predicate:

```
SELECT      g.home_team,
            IFNULL(SUM(g.home_wins), 0) AS formula ,
            t.*
FROM        games g
INNER JOIN _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id
GROUP BY    g.home_team 
ORDER BY    formula DESC;
```

To get those teams that haven't played a top 10 team at home, use `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE t.team_id IS NULL`:

```
SELECT      g.home_team,
            IFNULL(SUM(g.home_wins), 0) AS formula ,
            t.*
FROM        games g
LEFT JOIN _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id
WHERE t.team_id IS NULL
GROUP BY    g.home_team 
ORDER BY    formula DESC;
```

---

### Update:

You can do this using one query:

```
SELECT 
  g.home_team, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.team_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g.home_winsEND) AS formula,
  ...
FROM games g 
LEFT JOIN _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id 
GROUP BY g.home_team, ...;
```

Comment: I feel like I'm so close.  Is there a way to combine these two so that all the results are in the same select statement.  I tried using UNION but it gave me incorrect results.  Here's what I tried<code> block:SELECT      g.home_team,
         IFNULL(SUM(g.home_wins), 0) AS formula ,
         t.*
FROM        games g
INNER JOIN _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id
    
UNION

SELECT      g.home_team,
            SUM(0) AS formula ,
            t.*
FROM        games g
LEFT JOIN _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id
WHERE t.team_id IS NULL
GROUP BY    g.home_team 
ORDER BY    formula DESC;

Comment: So that comment didn't format the way I wanted, I'll add the UNION code I tried at the top

Comment: @JeremyBoht - You can do this using only one query, see my edit. But you have to include all the columns that are not involved in an aggregate function in the `GROUP BY` clause, please edit your question and show me some sample data from the two tables with the desired output that you looking for, so that I give you the correct query. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get everything to work using your updated example.